# How to change the color of one cell, compare values of two cells in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a dataset and a function that fills only the values in one column with a color, I want to compare this value with the value from another column. And if it is greater than in the other column, paint the cell in green, if not, then in red, but only in the first column

Here is a dataset and code that draws only the value in one column, and compares it to the static value 5.1

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.sample(n=10, random_state=1)
df
```

[image]

and function:

```
def highlight_cells(val):
    color = 'yellow' if val == 5.1 else ''
    return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

df.style.applymap(highlight_cells, subset=['petal_length'])
```

[image]

I want to compare the value of 'petal_length' with 'sepal_width' and if it is smaller, fill it in red, if not, fill it in green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.sample(n=10, random_state=1)

def highlight_cells(row):
    color = 'red' if row['petal_length'] < row['sepal_width'] else 'green'
    return ['background-color: {}'.format(color) if i == 'petal_length' else '' for i in row.index]

df.style.apply(highlight_cells, axis=1)
```

which gives

[image]